# Missing property in computed property name pattern

Tags: typescript

How can I solve the following TypeScript error : *Property 'item3' does not exist on type '{ item1: string; item2: string; }'.*?

I am using this computed property name pattern :

```
type items = 'item1' | 'item2' | 'item3'

const myItem = 'item1' as items

const computed : string = {item1 : 'value1', item2:'value2'}[myItem] ?? 'default'
```

I don't want to define all properties, that's why I have a default value returned.
I cannot have myItem undefined otherwise TS will throw Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICW5YFsDO8C88Dky0BGXeAHzwNQCYTz8VUBmWihgFhNAGMB7AO3Th4qSAEkG2VkRIBDTJXTd+g+L1TQArigAm8AFzxBAJ0R8A5pIDelQvrwBiGQCMuuADSUqe3Pa7bYuAC+ANoi4mgAuvAA-NEO-gBmuEA)

Comment: I am trying to get rid of the TS error Property xxx does not exist on type ...

Comment: change `as items` to `const myItem: items = 'item1'`: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAlsEFsDOUC8UDkdEEYNQB9NsEAmfIreBAZgwFgAoAYwHsA7JYKBEASWoAuWNRToquBiw5cobBGACu8ACZRhXAE4x2AczRQA3iRzrMAYgCGAI2YYANCVKCM55iogYAvgG1eAxABdKAB+EIsPADMMIA)